# How to generate spatial scale-free nwtworks?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sampling, network-topology

I want to generate spatial scale-free networks for my project. Are there any python libraries that enable it?

I read about the BA model (https://www.science.org/doi/pdf/10.1126/science.286.5439.509) which seems like the pioneer of scale-free networks but I am not sure it takes the spatial aspect into the account.

Can anyone explain:

1. What is the difference between a spatial and non-spatial scale-free network?
2. Python libraries to generate a spatial scale-free network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, with probability $p$ you create an edge, and otherwise a new vertex.

When creating edges, you consider the degree of the two vertices, and scale by $1/f(\text{dist}(v,u))$, where dist is typically the Euclidean distance.

When adding a new vertex, you put it randomly in $n$-dimensional space and connect it to some predefined number of vertices, subject to degree and scaled down similarly as above.

Comment: Reference: Modeling the Internet’s large-scale topology
Yook*, Jeong*†, Baraba´ si*‡

Comment: Thanks! Are you aware of any python libraries or github implementation that allows you do it?

Comment: You can use [networkx](https://networkx.org/nx-guides/content/generators/geometric.html). You have to do some work yourself, but it's enough to get you started.